# Difference between range and lte/gte django filters

Tags: django

I am using filters for a model with following two ways:

> Model.objects.filter(created_date__gte=datetime(2018, 1, 11, 00, 00, 00), created_date__lte=datetime(2018, 11, 11, 23, 59, 59), user_id=135)

And

> Model.objects.filter(user_id=135, created_date__range=["2018-11-1 00:00:00", "2018-11-11 23:59:59"])

When i check the count of the both filters there is huge difference of count.

The main question is what is difference between range and gte/lte in filters ?

While using postgres SQL raw query

> SELECT *, count(*) OVER() AS full_count FROM table_name 
>   WHERE user_id=135 AND created_date BETWEEN DATE('2018-11-01 00:00:00') AND DATE('2018-11-12 23:59:59') ORDER BY created_date;

counts are also different with django ORM

Comment: Do you have an example of an instance that is included in one of the queries but not in the other?

Comment: What would be the count if you use ***`datetime`*** object in **`range`** query, instead of ***string datetime***?

Comment: @JPG similar result count are coming in range with datetime object

Comment: @JPG kindly check question edit as well

Comment: `range` is inclusive at both ends, so it will include 2018-11-1 00:00:00. In the first example you used `gt`, not `gte`, so it's excluding 2018-11-1 00:00:00.

Comment: @arudzinska i forgot to enter it, just edit again. Okay just wanted to know what is the difference is there is there any difference for range and gte/lte ?